# Generate JS files from google sheets using app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a folder structure and javascript files based on the sheet name and the Type (column a). Where Type "Spec" starts i'd like to group everything between where "Spec" begins and ends and input the content into that file using Google App Script.

**Content Example**

[image]

**Desired Output**

[image]

[image]
**Code Example**

The current code I have to get this is below. But I'm currently not able to add the middle content in.

```
function export() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var filename = ""

  for (var i in sheets) {

    var name = sheets[i].getSheetName();
    var fo = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);
    var folder = fo.hasNext() ? fo.next() : DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFolder(name);

    var values = sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues();
    values.shift();
    var type, title, value, emptyCode, code;

    for (var j in values) {
      [type, title, value, emptyCode, code] = values[j];        
      if (type == "Spec") {
        var filename = title+'.js'
        folder.getFilesByName(filename).hasNext() || folder.createFile(filename, code, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to help you, but I am not sure what you mean with "not able to add the middle content in" - what is the "middle content"? And also " group everything between where "Spec" begins and ends" is not quite clear - you have a type "Spec" almost in every line.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. For example... The spec begins at row 2 (cell 2B will be the file name). Column E for Row 2, 3, 4 and 5 are all the content I would like to add into the file. A new Spec begins at row 6, therefor a new file will be created and add in the content from column E for row 6, 7, 8 and 9. I hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Two things

1. Values is a 2-D array  - you need to address single values by specifying a row and a column indices, e.g. `values[0][1]` or `values[i][4]`
2. You need to specify the beginning and end of the content of each file. This can be done with the method `indexOf()` to verify in which rows `type == "Spec"` is fullfilled or with a combination of two nested `for` loops and an `if` statement.

Here is a sample of how to implement the functionality with the nested loops and statement combination:

```
function export() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 
  for (var i in sheets) {    
    var name = sheets[i].getSheetName();
    var fo = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name);
    var folder = fo.hasNext() ? fo.next() : DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFolder(name);    
    var values = sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues();
    var type, title, value, emptyCode, code;
    loop1:
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      type = values[j][0];
      if (type == "Spec") {
        var title = values[j][4];
        var filename = title+'.js';
        var code = "";
        loop2:
        for (i = j+1; i < values.length; i++){          
          if (values[i][0] != "Spec"){
            code += values[i][4] + "\n";
          } else {
            break loop2;
          }          
        }
        folder.getFilesByName(filename).hasNext() || folder.createFile(filename, code, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit the code slightly to add the title into the file and change the filename.

```
function generateStories() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 
  for (var i in sheets) {    
    var sheetName = sheets[2].getSheetName();
    var fo = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(sheetName);
    var folder = fo.hasNext() ? fo.next() : DriveApp.getRootFolder().createFolder(sheetName);    
    var values = sheets[2].getDataRange().getValues();
    var type, title, code;
    loop1:
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      type = values[j][0];
      if (type == "Spec") {
        var title = values[j][1];
        var filename = title+'.spec';
        var code = values[j][4] + "\n";
        loop2:
        for (i = j+1; i < values.length; i++){          
          if (values[i][0] != "Spec"){
            code += values[i][4] + "\n";
          } else {
            break loop2;
          }          
        }
        folder.getFilesByName(filename).hasNext() || folder.createFile(filename, code, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
      }
    }
  }
}
```